# Thanks, but I have eaten

Tags: idiomatic-language

> Would you like something?
>
> Thanks, but I have eaten.

Would "I have eaten" be natural?

Comment: Yes, it is perfectly natural.

Answer (score 1):

I speech I'd contract the I have to "I've eaten",  and I might add "already".  But the grammatical construction is natural.